# Xdebug is disabled, but I still have errors creating a new laravel app or updating composer

Tags: php, wamp, xdebug

I get this error while trying to create a new laravel application in my Git bash. I've tried to update composer, but got a similar error. After checking google for possible solutions, I was told to disable zend debug in php. ini file. Now my php. ini file has the following, I guess this means xdebug is disable

> zend_extension =
>   "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
>   xdebug.remote_autostart=off
>   xdebug.remote_enable = off
>   xdebug.profiler_enable = off

But this didn't solve the problem.

**Here is the error while trying to create a new laravel app:**

> $ laravel new rentapp Crafting application... You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime
>   performance. See getcomposer. org/xdebug
>   php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');" You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime        performance.
>   See https:// getcomposer. org/xdebug
>
> > php artisan clear-compiled
>
> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp\www\rentapp\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed
>   t       o open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\rentapp\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0003     236424   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\rentapp\artisan:0
>       0.0470     239328   2. require('C:\wamp\www\rentapp\bootstrap\autoload.php')
>   C:\wamp\www\rentapp\artisan:16
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp\www\rentapp\bootstrap/.       ./vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\rentapp\boo
>   tstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0003     236424   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\rentapp\artisan:0
>       0.0470     239328   2. require('C:\wamp\www\rentapp\bootstrap\autoload.php')
>   C:\wamp\www\rentapp\artisan:16
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event
>   returned w       ith an error
>
> [RuntimeException]   Error Output: run-script [--dev] [--no-dev]
>   [-l|--list] [--] [] []...
>
> Application ready! Build something amazing.

I get a similar error when i try to do composer update or diagnose

Attached is my php.ini file. [Here is my php.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylKL7.png)

Thanks in anticipation for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**How to disable xdebug?**

According to your error message xdebug is still enabled.

Put a `;` in front of the `zend_extension` line (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylKL7.png) (to comment it out).

```
;zend_extension = "<path\to\php\ext\>php_xdebug.dll"
```

---

**How to find the `php.ini` file?**

Run `php -ini` on the console and edit the `php.ini` file shown after `Loaded Configuration File:`.

After editing the file run `php -m` - and ensure that xdebug is not listed in the Zend Extension section.

Comment: I think you are not editing the right `php.ini` file. Run `php -ini` on the console and edit the `php.ini` file shown after `Loaded Configuration File:`. After editing the file run `php -m` - and ensure that xdebug is not listed in the Zend Extension section.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help again. I got this line `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\WINDOWS `. Now I'm in my C:\windows directory. There are so many folders here, any possible ideas on where the php.ini file might be located? I did a search, but didn't work.

Comment: Not `C:\Windows` ... please read again: edit the `php.ini` file shown after `Loaded Configuration File:`!

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the version of PHP that you are running on the console is the same as the PHP that you are running in your web server.

It is possible that the PHP your webserver is running has a different `php.ini` configuration file, so even though Xdebug has been disabled on the web server, it still is not disabled for the CLI.

Run `php -i`.

Find the line that says `Loaded Configuration File`... this will point out the .ini file that your PHP file is actually loading.

Note that you need to comment the line `zend_extension = "C:\\[...]php_xdebug[...].dll"`. You can do that by adding a '`;`' at the front of the line.

Comment: Thanks guys, I saw this `Loaded Configuration File => C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini`
When I went to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12` directory, there were 3 php.ini files. 1 is `php.ini-install` 2. `php.ini-development` 3. `php.ini-production` and I discovered that the `zend_extension = "C:\\[...]php_xdebug[...].dll"` was missing in all 3. I added the line and appended >; to it. I also added these lines to the `[xdebug]`
`xdebug.remote_autostart=off`
`xdebug.remote_enable = off`
`xdebug.profiler_enable = off` Then tried creating a new laravel app and composer self-update but same error.

Comment: @Jens A. Koch  I really appreciate your efforts. Maybe I'll try uninstalling and reinstalling wamp. I would still appreciate your inputs, else, I understand you guys have really tried. I'm just a lady trying to learn to code, but I won't give up till I make this work.

Answer (score 0):

note if your using php5-fpm and have different php.ini for /etc/php4/fpm and /etc/php5/cli you will need to disable both

The errors shown aren't down to xdebug being installed or not its that composer cant find your autoloader.

The notification about xdebug from composer is just a performance  notice, you are fine to run xdebug and composer in a local enviroment